# read String and int from file in additional to read from user

Tags: java, file, txt

I know how to read manually an input from user, but I'v none pre knowledge about files (or collections, or any advanced material, just loops, arrays ,polymorphism, and some basic implementation of linked lists stack etc.), so I hope I'm not asking too much here.

I was asked in homework to get input from the user manually, and in addition, to read input commands from txt file.

this is a short version of what i'v wrote so far (only manually):

```
import java.util.*;
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  ...
  while(!exitProgram)
    {
      System.out.print("choose type of list: 1)sorted. 2)unsorted.\n");
      int listOption = input.nextInt();
      if(listOption == 1)
        {
          while(!exitSorteds)
             {
              System.out.print("choose action: 1)create list. 2)insert x.\n");
              System.out.print("3)Union previous.4)Extract Min.5)exit sorteds.\n");
              
              int actionOption = input.nextInt();
              int i = 0;
              switch(actionOption)
                {
                  case 1 :
                  ..
 
                }
             }
        }
       else
        {
          ...
        }
    }
}
```

An example of the txt file:

CreateList

Insert 6

Insert 8

CreateList

Insert 5

Union

ExtractMin

Exit

How do i read this txt file? and there is a way to combine the read from the file, with the manually read from the user that i'v already wrote?

Comment: Why u are not reading file line by line? If u are using java 8 simply u could read it as stream of string https://mkyong.com/java8/java-8-stream-read-a-file-line-by-line/

Comment: I have string and int in the same line, how do I read it and save it?

Comment: int also a string, if you dont care to parse it read all as a string and save